# SHA1 value of a string gives different result

Tags: git, openssl

I'm reading the git documentation on the object storage and I'm trying to understand how is the digest created ?
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

They mentioned the following:

```
>> store = header + content
=> "blob 16\u0000what is up, doc?"
>> require 'digest/sha1'
=> true
>> sha1 = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(store)
=> "bd9dbf5aae1a3862dd1526723246b20206e5fc37"
```

I tried hashing "blob 16\u0000what is up, doc?" in different online tools but still not the same result. I'm assuming it's the null byte \u0000 that is causing the issue here.

Also tried to test it in main.c file but still not the same result:

```
int main() {
    std::string store = "blob 16\u0000what is up, doc?"; // The input string

    unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH]; // SHA-1 produces a 20-byte (160-bit) hash

    // Calculate the SHA-1 hash
    SHA1(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(store.c_str()), store.length(), hash);

    // Convert the hash to a hexadecimal string
    char hash_str[2 * SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
        sprintf(&hash_str[i * 2], "%02x", hash[i]);
    }
    hash_str[2 * SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH] = '\0';

    std::cout << "SHA-1 Hash: " << hash_str << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
SHA-1 Hash: ef04a980b37021f6534130548617df7588eac70f
```

How can I get the same result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ printf 'blob 16\0what is up, doc?' | sha1sum
bd9dbf5aae1a3862dd1526723246b20206e5fc37  -
$
```

You're getting bit by different languages' handling of nul bytes. C++ uses C string conventions, strings passed as pointers to their first byte end at the  first nul, but tell it about the underlying char array and it can deal:

```
$ sh -x <<\---- 
cat <<\EOD >stwnul.cc
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
        std::string foo("blob 16\u0000what is up, doc?");
        std::cout << foo.size() <<' ' <<foo <<'\n';
        const char data[] = "blob 16\u0000what is up, doc?";
        std::string bar(data,sizeof data -1);
        std::cout << bar.size() <<' ' <<bar <<'\n';
}
EOD
c++ -march=native -pipe -Os    stwnul.cc -o stwnul
./stwnul
----
+ cat
+ c++ -march=native -pipe -Os stwnul.cc -o stwnul
+ ./stwnul
7 blob 16
24 blob 16what is up, doc?
$
```